# QT New Ui and Shared Pointer

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, smart-pointers

I am trying to build a UI which reads a json file and displays the information in QT UI.There are mainly three classes involved Travelagency(a class which reads the json file), Holiday(Main UI) and New_Customer(Second UI ,which adds new customers to existing customers in travelagency).

In my holiday UI inorder to read the file I have used just a normal instance of Travelagency(**Travelagency travelagency**) in order to fetch the data. So here is where I am stuck, In order to check if a customer exists or not my new_customer class only takes shared pointer instance of travelagency in its constructor.I can open the second ui only from first ui and I dont understand how can I pass the "Travelagency travelagency" instance from may main ui to the secondary ui which tkaes only shared pointers.

Here is what I have tried......

```
    void holiday::on_action_triggered()//New Customer Menu
{    
    std::shared_ptr<Travelagency> travelagencyptr = std::make_shared<Travelagency>(travelagency);
    std::shared_ptr<New_Customer> main = std::make_shared<New_Customer>(travelagencyptr);
    New Customer->show();
}
```

The second disppaers when try calling it with smart pointer and when I later on try to call the second ui using "new" the ui shows up but the added instance of customer disappears in vector when added to it. If required I can provide additional information.

Comment: You cannot pass a normal instance to a function requiring a shared_ptr. You could copy your instance into a freshly created shared_ptr but that's probably not what you want to do. I would create a shared_ptr from the start.

Comment: From your code snippet the second ui ‘new_customer’ disappearrs because as soon as you out of scope shared_ptr counter goes to zero and it free the memory.

Comment: Most of the things in Qt have parent-children relations. Think about who is a parent of what in your case. Probably `Holiday` has `NewCustomer`, and `TravelAgency` should be just called `JsonReader` and used as a tool, not part of UI. Then you can just hold the [shared]ptrs as your member fields.